# Symfony array of arrays

Tags: arrays, symfony

Maybe there is a simpler way of doing this. But I want to display entries (URLs) that were already found when trying to input in to a database table along with the current table. So in the controller I am trying to pass two arrays. One that is of the whole table and another of the entries it found matched the entries in the table. So the user can see they already existed.

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ObjectBundle:object');

foreach ($mylinks as &$value) {
    $linkexist = $repository->findOneByUrl($value);

    if (!$linkexist) {
        $obj = new Object();
        $obj->setUrl($value);
        $obj->setLastupdate(new \DateTime('now'));

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($obj);
        $em->flush();
    } else {    
        $notfound = new Object();
        $notfound->setUrl($value);
    }
}

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$listurls = $em->getRepository('ObjectBundle:Object')->findAll();

return $this->render('object/index.html.twig', array(
    'objects' => $listurls,
));
```

I would like to include the $notfound into a separate array or parse it without changing the Object entity. Any ideas?

Comment: Your naming suggests you want something else, at least to me. The `$notfound` should really be `$existing` or at least `$found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `Object` contains some sort of `Id` and it can be used here:

```
$existingIds = array();
$k=0;
```

Then collect the IDs:

```
} else {    
    $notfound = new Object();
    $notfound->setUrl($value);
    $nfound[$k]=$notfound;
    $k++;
}
```

Pass the array:

```
return $this->render('object/index.html.twig', array(
    'objects' => $listurls,
    'existingIds' => $existingIds
));
```

Finally, in your `Twig`, you would have something like this:

```
{% if existingIds is defined %}
    {% for existingId in existingIds %}
        {{ existingId.url }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I just needed to add an array to hold the $notfound URLs and then pass that as a separate array like this:

return $this->render('proofpoint/index.html.twig', array(
    'proofpoints' => $listurls,'notfounds' => $nfound));

I am going to modify your response and then give you credit. Thanks!!

Comment: Sure, glad I could help :)

Comment: Though, you **really** do not need that `$k` :)

Comment: Tried that but just wrote over first entry in array.